# Why are Standard iterator ranges [begin, end) instead of [begin, end]?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, language-lawyer

Why does the Standard define `end()` as one past the end, instead of at the actual end?

Comment: I'm guessing "because that's what the standard says" won't cut it, right? :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Of course not. That would erode our respect for the (people behind) the standard. We should expect that there's a *reason* for the choices made by the standard.

Comment: I guess, this explanation also deserves your attention: [One Past the End](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/iterators.html#iterators.predefined.end)

Comment: In short, computers don't count like people. But if you're curious as to why people don't count like computers, I recommend [The Nothing that Is: A Natural History of Zero](http://www.oup.com/us/companion.websites/0195128427/) for an in-depth look at the trouble humans had discovering that there is a number which is one less than one.

Comment: Because there's only one way to generate "last one", it is often not cheap because it has to be real.  Generating "you fell off the end of the cliff" is *always* cheap, many possible representations will do.  (void*)"ahhhhhhh" will do fine.

Comment: This is one of those rare questions where it *is* appropriate to talk about "the STL". The `[begin, end)` convention comes from the original HP/SGI version of the STL.

Comment: @MSalters: I believe that it's present in the C Standard, too, where it is legal to take the address of one-past-the-end of an array, which is AFAIK older than the STL and may have origins even earlier.

Comment: You know, I asked this question in a different form and got a very poor showing of results. It's all in how you ask I guess. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441749/representing-intervals-or-ranges

Comment: Because you want to be able to specify the empty sequence like `[a,a)` and not `[a,a-1]`. The later is just plain ugly.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

The best argument easily is the one made by [Dijkstra himself](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html):

- You want the size of the range to be a simple difference *end* − *begin*;
- including the lower bound is more "natural" when sequences degenerate to empty ones, and also because the alternative (*excluding* the lower bound) would require the existence of a "one-before-the-beginning" sentinel value.

You still need to justify why you start counting at zero rather than one, but that wasn't part of your question.

The wisdom behind the [begin, end) convention pays off time and again when you have any sort of algorithm that deals with multiple nested or iterated calls to range-based constructions, which chain naturally. By contrast, using a doubly-closed range would incur off-by-ones and extremely unpleasant and noisy code. For example, consider a partition [*n*<sub>0</sub>, *n*<sub>1</sub>)[*n*<sub>1</sub>, *n*<sub>2</sub>)[*n*<sub>2</sub>,*n*<sub>3</sub>). Another example is the standard iteration loop `for (it = begin; it != end; ++it)`, which runs `end - begin` times. The corresponding code would be much less readable if both ends were inclusive – and imagine how you'd handle empty ranges.

Finally, we can also make a nice argument why counting should start at zero: With the half-open convention for ranges that we just established, if you are given a range of *N* elements (say to enumerate the members of an array), then 0 is the natural "beginning" so that you can write the range as [0, *N*), without any awkward offsets or corrections.

In a nutshell: the fact that we don't see the number `1` everywhere in range-based algorithms is a direct consequence of, and motivation for, the [begin, end) convention.

Comment: The typical C for loop iterating over an array of size N is "for(i=0;i<N;i++) a[i]=0;".  Now, you can't express that directly with iterators - many folks wasted time trying to make < meaningful.  But it is almost equally obvious to say "for(i=0;i!=N;i++)..."  Mapping 0 to begin and N to end is therefore convenient.

Comment: @KrazyGlew: I didn't put types in my loop example deliberately. If you think of `begin` and `end` as `int`s with values `0` and `N`, respectively, it fits perfectly. Arguably, it's the `!=` condition that's more natural than the traditional `<`, but we never discovered that until we started thinking about more general collections.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I agree that "we never dscovered that [!= is better] until we started thinking about more general collections." IMHO that is one of the things Stepanov deserves credit for - speaking as someone who tried to write such template libraries before the STL.   However, I'll argue about "!=" being more natural - or, rather, I'll argue that != has probably introduced bugs, that < would catch.  Think for(i=0;i!=100;i+=3)...

Comment: @KrazyGlew: Your last point is somewhat off-topic, since the sequence {0, 3, 6, ..., 99} is not of the form that the OP asked about. If you wanted it to be thus, you should write a `++`-incrementable iterator template `step_by<3>`, which would then have the originally advertised semantics.

Comment: @KrazyGlew Even if < would sometime hide a bug, **it is a bug anyway**. If someone use `!=` when he should use `<`, then **it is** a bug. By the way, that king of error is easy to find with unit testing or assertions.

Answer (score 89):

Actually, a lot of iterator related stuff suddenly makes much more sense if you consider the iterators not pointing *at* the elements of the sequence but *in between*, with dereferencing accessing the next element right to it. Then the "one past end" iterator suddenly makes immediate sense:

```
   +---+---+---+---+
   | A | B | C | D |
   +---+---+---+---+
   ^               ^
   |               |
 begin            end
```

Obviously `begin` points to the beginning of the sequence, and `end` points to the end of the same sequence. Dereferencing `begin` accesses the element `A`, and dereferencing `end` makes no sense because there's no element right to it. Also, adding an iterator `i` in the middle gives

```
   +---+---+---+---+
   | A | B | C | D |
   +---+---+---+---+
   ^       ^       ^
   |       |       |
 begin     i      end
```

and you immediately see that the range of elements from `begin` to `i` contains the elements `A` and `B` while the range of elements from `i` to `end` contains the elements `C` and `D`. Dereferencing `i` gives the element right of it, that is the first element of the second sequence.

Even the "off-by-one" for reverse iterators suddenly becomes obvious that way: Reversing that sequence gives:

```
   +---+---+---+---+
   | D | C | B | A |
   +---+---+---+---+
   ^       ^       ^
   |       |       |
rbegin     ri     rend
 (end)    (i)   (begin)
```

I've written the corresponding non-reverse (base) iterators in parentheses below. You see, the reverse iterator belonging to `i` (which I've named `ri`) *still* points in between elements `B` and `C`. However due to reversing the sequence, now element `B` is on the right to it.

Comment: This is IMHO the best answer, though I think it might be better illustrated if the iterators pointed at numbers, and the elements were between the numbers (the syntax `foo[i]`) is a shorthand for the item immediately *after* position `i`).  Thinking about it, I wonder if it might be useful for a language to have separate operators for "item immediately after position i" and "item immediately before position i", since a lot of algorithms work with pairs of adjacent items, and saying "The items on either side of position i" may be cleaner than "The items at positions i and i+1".

Comment: @supercat: The numbers were not supposed to indicate iterator positions/indices, but to indicate the elements themselves. I'll replace the numbers with letters to make that clearer. Indeed, with the numbers as given, `begin[0]` (assuming a random access iterator) would access element `1`, since there's no element `0` in my example sequence.

Comment: Why is the word "begin" used rather than "start"? After all, "begin" is a verb.

Comment: @user1741137 I think "begin" is meant to be the abbreviation of "beginning" (which now makes sense). "beginning" being too long, "begin" sounds like a nice fit. "start" would be conflicting with the verb "start" (for example when you have to define a function `start()` in your class for starting a specific process or whatever, it would be annoying if it conflicts with an already existing one).

Answer (score 75):

**Why does the Standard define `end()` as one past the end, instead of at the actual end?**

Because:

1. It avoids special handling for empty ranges. For empty ranges, `begin()` is equal to
   `end()` &
2. It makes the end criterion simple for loops that iterate over the elements: The loops simply
   continue as long as `end()` is not reached.

Answer (score 65):

Because then

```
size() == end() - begin()   // For iterators for whom subtraction is valid
```

and you won't have to do **awkward** things like

```
// Never mind that this is INVALID for input iterators...
bool empty() { return begin() == end() + 1; }
```

and you won't accidentally write **erroneous code** like

```
bool empty() { return begin() == end() - 1; }    // a typo from the first version
                                                 // of this post
                                                 // (see, it really is confusing)

bool empty() { return end() - begin() == -1; }   // Signed/unsigned mismatch
// Plus the fact that subtracting is also invalid for many iterators
```

Also: **What would `find()` return if `end()` pointed to a valid element?**
Do you *really* want *another* member called `invalid()` which returns an invalid iterator?!
Two iterators is already painful enough...

Oh, and **see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/18/75652.aspx) related post**.

---

### Also:

If the `end` was before the last element, how would you **`insert()` at the true end?!**

Answer (score 24):

The iterator idiom of half-closed ranges `[begin(), end())` is originally based on pointer arithmetic for plain arrays. In that mode of operation, you would have functions that were passed an array and a size.

```
void func(int* array, size_t size)
```

Converting to half-closed ranges `[begin, end)` is very simple when you have that information:

```
int* begin;
int* end = array + size;

for (int* it = begin; it < end; ++it) { ... }
```

To work with fully-closed ranges, it's harder:

```
int* begin;
int* end = array + size - 1;

for (int* it = begin; it <= end; ++it) { ... }
```

Since pointers to arrays are iterators in C++ (and the syntax was designed to allow this), it's much easier to call `std::find(array, array + size, some_value)` than it is to call `std::find(array, array + size - 1, some_value)`.

---

Plus, if you work with half-closed ranges, you can use the `!=` operator to check for the end condition, becuase (if your operators are defined correctly) `<` implies `!=`.

```
for (int* it = begin; it != end; ++ it) { ... }
```

However there's no easy way to do this with fully-closed ranges. You're stuck with `<=`.

The only kind of iterator that supports `<` and `>` operations in C++ are random-access iterators. If you had to write a `<=` operator for every iterator class in C++, you'd have to make all of your iterators fully comparable, and you'd fewer choices for creating less capable iterators (such as the bidirectional iterators on `std::list`, or the input iterators that operate on `iostreams`) if C++ used fully-closed ranges.

Answer (score 9):

With the `end()` pointing one past the end, it is easy to iterate a collection with a for loop:

```
for (iterator it = collection.begin(); it != collection.end(); it++)
{
    DoStuff(*it);
}
```

With `end()` pointing to the last element, a loop would be more complex:

```
iterator it = collection.begin();
while (!collection.empty())
{
    DoStuff(*it);

    if (it == collection.end())
        break;

    it++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If a container is empty, `begin() == end()`.
2. C++ Programmers tend to use `!=` instead of `<` (less than) in loop conditions, therefore
   having `end()` pointing to a position one off-the-end is convenient.