# Generator list with c++ standard library?

Tags: c++, iterator, std

Does the C++ standard library include any mechanism to produce a list-like iterable range that uses an injected generator function to return the value at each position? i.e. something that could give behavior analogous to C#'s `yield return` or F#'s `yield` list comprehensions? The ideal would be:

```
hypothetical_generator_list<size_t> l([](size_t index) { return index * 2; });
assert(l[4] == 8);
assert(*(l.begin() + 1000000000) == 2000000000);
```

Motivation: I would like to do a binary search over a space of hundreds of billions of (monotonically increasing) values. But `std::lower_bound` wants iterators, and it would be completely impossible to put all the values into anything like a `vector`. However, I could easily write a function that, given an index, does a few calculations and returns the value at that index.

```
hypothetical_generator_list<size_t> c([](size_t index) { return index * 2; });
auto itFound = std::lower_bound(l.begin(), l.begin() + 100000000000, 6000);
assert(itFound - l.begin() == 3000);
```

I could write my own custom iterator, but that seems like a lot of work compared to just passing a simple lambda to a constructor. And of course I could just write the binary search myself (but what fun would that be?). Are those the only choices?

For posterity, here are a couple links I found on the subject:

[Equivalent C++ to Python generator pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059187/equivalent-c-to-python-generator-pattern)

http://www.sirver.net/blog/2011/08/19/generators-in-c++/

But it seems the answer is that there is no way to do this that is simpler than just writing a binary search.

Comment: This does not strike me as something that a *container* should be used for at all.  Seems like a mathematical or logical process, rather.

Comment: @John You are correct. I am attempting to get iterators over the output space of a function so I can leverage the standard library algorithms to search it. I will edit the word "container" out of the question.

Comment: this seems similar to what you are asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511711/initializing-stdvector-with-iterative-function-calls also you might want to check: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algorithms won't give you the index while scanning over the range. You can use boost.Iterator (or Boost.range) to help you to write your iterator (either `[boost::iterator_facade][1]` or `[boost::function_input_iterator][2]`for instance)

Comment: +1, [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) makes this task easy.

Comment: @JBentley It *looks* like I could get what I want by combining `counting_iterator` (which is lazy) with `transform_iterator`. And though a strict logician would disagree, based on the fact that boost added these, I'll conclude there is no simple way to get this behavior using the standard library alone.

Answer (score 0):

It may work

```
template<int X >       
class ListGenerator
{
  public:
    int operator[](int Y){ return X*Y;}
};

int main()
{
    ListGenerator<5> lg;
    cout<<lg[5]<<endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

you can modify template parameter list to add as many as you need.

Comment: Something like that would give me `[]` semantics, but not the iterators I'd need to use the standard library algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
std::size_t index = 0;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(list), count, [&index]
{
    return index++ * 2;
});
```

Here we're populating list with count elements from our generator function (the lambda).