# In C how to get number of items in array of pointers to char strings

Tags: c, arrays

I want to implement the following function to print the contents of several `char` strings which are referenced through a pointer array.  How can I determine how many pointers there are without passing the total as an argument of the function?

If it was an array of type `int` then it would be possible to use the `sizeof()` function but given that each item of my array is a pointer to a `char` string and each string could be of different length I don't think I can use this approach.

```
void printCharArray(char *arr[]){

    int length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(char); /* this does not give correct 
                                          number of items in the pointer array */

    for (int i=1;i<=length; i++) {
        printf("Array item: [%s]",arr[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: "How can I determine how many pointers there are without passing the total as an argument of the function?" – you can't. This is why every function that writes into arrays in the stdlib takes a count argument.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this as C does not track the number of elements in an array for you like this.

You have a couple of options:

1. Pass the number of items in the array.
2. Set the last item to NULL so the code knows when it's reached the end. (This is kind of how C strings are handled.)
3. Otherwise modify your data structures to track the number of items in the array.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot pass arrays as function arguments in C. Array names decay to pointers to their first element when used as a function argument, and you must separately specify the number of available array elements.

(In the context of a function parameter type, `T[]` and `T*` and `T[12]` are identical, so your function paramter might as well be `char ** arr`.)

Like so:

```
void printCharArray(char ** arr, size_t len) { /* ... */ }

int main()
{
    char * arr[10] = { "Hello", "World", /* ... */ };

    printCharArray(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));
}
```

(Alternatively you can supply a "first" and a "one-past-the-end" pointer, which might be a [bit more natural](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9963438/596781).)

Comment: That's interesting, so `sizeof(arr)` will give the size of the memory occupied by the pointer to the whole array and `sizeof(*arr)` will give the size occupied by a pointer to an item in the array which in this case is a pointer of a char string?

Comment: Could the size calculation be done inside the printCharArray() function body?

Comment: @NSDigital No, in `printCharArray()`, there is no array, only a pointer. You can calculate the size that way **only for real arrays**, not for pointers, even if they point to the first element of an array.

Comment: @NSDigital: `sizeof` for *arrays* gives you the entire size, but inside the function *there is no array*. There is only a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the element after the last valid element to null then you can do:

```
void printCharArray(char *arr[]){

    for (int i=0; arr[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("Array item: [%s]",arr[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void printCharArray(char *arr[]) {
    int length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(char*); /* this does not give correct 
                                                 number of items in the pointer array */
    for (int i=0;i<=length; i++) {
        printf("Array item: [%s]",arr[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char * arr[10] = { "Hello", "World", /* ... */ };
    printCharArray(arr); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first I declared y as a global var. htmTags is a *char[]. then in main()

```
y = 0;
while( htmTags[y] ) {
        y++;
}
```

I did not add null at the end of array. provides actual count of array elements

or this works too
    for (y=0;htmTags[y];y++) ;