# Invalid use of non-static data member when setting begin iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, iterator, inner-classes

I'm writing a tree that follows this header:

```cpp
class TreeLetters {
private:
    Letter* root;

public:
    // ...

    Letter* Root () const;

    class iterator {
    private:
        Letter* it;

    public:
        iterator ();
        iterator (Letter* letter);
        iterator (const iterator & other);

        iterator begin ();
        iterator end   ();

        // ...
    };
};
```

As simple as it is, I'm getting an error with the iterator's `begin()` method, which is as follows:

```cpp
TreeLetters::iterator TreeLetters::iterator :: begin () {
    return iterator(root); // invalid use of non-static data member 'TreeLetters:root'
}
```

I've been reading some old questions and the only solution that has at least swept the problem under the rug for me is making the root `static`, which creates the greater problem of not being able to have more than one tree.

I've tried making the root `protected` and adding a `friend class TreeLetters` to the private members of the iterator, but nothing has worked. I'm also working with C++11.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks to me like begin() and end() should be in TreeLetters not in iterator. begin/methods usually return iterators but are not part of the iterator class rather its container.

Comment: You're right, moving the definitions to TreeLetters solved it! Add it as an answer if you like :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my point of view, the iterator must have the whole tree (which is a pointer to tree root), not a reference to current letter. You can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20966749/6941952).
I hope that helps solve your problem.