# Qt container (QVector, QList) ::end() return an iterator which cannot be referred

Tags: c++, qt

## [Situation]

This happens on both `QVector` and `QList` and here I used the latter as an example.

**Test code:**

```
QList<int> test;    
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    test.append(i);

// First
qDebug()<<"[First]";
qDebug()<<"Directly return:"<<test.first();
QList<int>::iterator itr_first = test.begin();
qDebug()<<"By iterator:"<<*itr_first;

// Last
qDebug()<<"[Last]";
qDebug()<<"Directly return:"<<test.last();
QList<int>::iterator itr_last = test.end();
qDebug()<<"By iterator:"<<*itr_last; //<--- ***No value can be referred from here***

itr_last = itr_last-1;
qDebug()<<"By iterator(modified):"<<*itr_last;
```

**The output is:**

> [First]
>
> Directly return: 0
>
> By iterator: 0
>
> [Last]
>
> Directly return: 9
>
> By iterator: -842150451
>
> By iterator(modified): 9

## [Question]

Unlike `QList::begin()` which returns the iterator of the first item, I don't understand why `QList::end()` return an unusable iterator which cannot be referred. This is very nettlesome to me and makes my program sometimes buggy.

What's the reason for it? Does it have anything to do with C++ convetion?

Comment: Please read up on half-open ranges and off-the end iterators, the concepts behind `begin` and `end` are fundamental to C++ (and well, anything in programming really).

Comment: Thanks, I kinda lack the background of this.

Comment: @KubaOber I am the OP, and I think it's duplicated too. Is it pertinent that I just delete it myself?

Comment: Yes, but in the future check for duplicates first. Users who delete many answered questions will be suspended for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iterator that `QList::end()` returns (like all `end` iterators in STL-like containers) does not refer to an element of the list - it's strictly for use as a sentinel marker. It's never valid to dereference it.

From the Qt docs (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html):

`QList::end()`

> Returns an STL-style iterator pointing to the imaginary item after the last item in the list.

`QList::last()`

> Returns a reference to the last item in the list. The list must not be empty. If the list can be empty, call isEmpty() before calling this function.

Comment: Thanks, though I was expecting some discussion [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963401/why-are-standard-iterator-ranges-begin-end-instead-of-begin-end)

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation here: `iterator QList::end ()`

You can see: `Returns an STL-style iterator pointing to the imaginary item after the last item in the list.`

You just have to consider that the end element is not a valid element. You can go all over the list using something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    qDebug() << list.at(i);
}
```