# Why does frexp() not yield scientific notation?

Tags: c, floating-point, posix, ieee-754

Scientific notation is the common way to express a number with an explicit order of magnitude. First a nonzero digit, then a radix point, then a fractional part, and the exponent. In binary, there is only one possible nonzero digit.

Floating-point math involves an implicit first digit equal to one, then the mantissa bits "follow the radix point."

So why does `frexp()` put the radix point to the left of the implicit bit, and return a number in [0.5, 1) instead of scientific-notation-like [1, 2)? Is there some overflow to beware of?

Effectively it subtracts one more than the bias value specified by IEEE 754/ISO 60559. In hardware, this potentially trades an addition for an XOR. Alone, that seems like a pretty weak argument, considering that in many cases getting back to normal will require another floating-point operation.

Comment: I think this question can be simplified: In traditional text-book scientific notation for a number base *b*, the significant is chosen to lie in the range [1, *b*). But `frexp` uses the convention to put the significand in the range [1 / *b*, 1). Which one is right? Which one is better? I think it's a bit like asking whether range indexes should start at zero or at one.

Comment: @KerrekSB Actually, I'm just implementing a logarithm library now, and `frexp` is *not* appropriate for that. The integral part of the logarithm is what would be returned for the [1, 2) convention. I guess my question could be answered with examples of applicability of [1/b, 1), but really I'm wondering why `frexp` was designed this way, by whoever originally designed it.

Comment: You're right - in fact, `[1, b)` is just the exponential of the range `[0, 1)`, which we already agreed was [the right way to denote ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9963401/596781).

Comment: `frexp()` does yield "scientific notation". "scientific notation" is `a` times `power(base, exponent)`  [Ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). `a` isn't obliged to a narrow range. A "normalized scientific notation" has a restricted range for `a`. First a nonzero digit, then a radix point, then a fractional part, and the exponent." is an overly narrow definition of "scientific notation". The post is still a _good_ question as to why `frexp()` returns a `significand` and `exponent` as it does. It is that the title could state the issue in a more direct and unbiased fashion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [rationale](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/d5.html#4-5-4-2) says:

> **4.5.4.2 The frexp function**
>
> The functions frexp, ldexp, and modf are primitives used by the
>   remainder of the library. There was some sentiment for dropping them
>   for the same reasons that ecvt, fcvt, and gcvt were dropped, but their
>   adherents rescued them for general use. Their use is problematic: on
>   nonbinary architectures ldexp may lose precision, and frexp may be
>   inefficient.

One can speculate that the “remainder of the library” was more convenient to write with `frexp`'s convention, or was already traditionally written against this interface although it did not provide any benefit.

I know that this does not fully answer the question, but it did not quite fit inside a comment.

I should also point out that some of the choices made in the design of the C language predate IEEE 754. **Perhaps the format returned by `frexp` made sense with the PDP-11's floating-point format(s)**, or any other architecture on which a function `frexp` was first introduced. EDIT: See also page 155 of the [manual](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2005/readings/pdp11-40.pdf) for one PDP-11 model.

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly more than a comment! Not surprising that its genesis was UNIX, but it's interesting that someone once tried to kill it.

Comment: Yes, the PDP-11 floating point is documented as having the binary point to the left of the "hidden" bit... So for exponent == 0, the number is, as per frexp(), 0.5..0.99999...  Interestingly, there is little difference between the PDP-11 and IEEE formats -- in effect the difference is the bias applied to the exponent, for IEEE the bias is 127 (for single length) where for the PDP-11 the same bit pattern (modulo byte ordering) has (effectively) a bias of 129.

Comment: @gmch That would make a great answer. It smells like a smoking gun, even if we can't be sure there's no other reason.

Comment: Actually, I'll just accept this. See page 155 of [this manual](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2005/readings/pdp11-40.pdf).