# How to get the mantissa and exponent of a double in a power of 10?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, double-precision

I saw the function `double frexp (double x, int* exp);`, which splits a double into the mantissa (m) and the exponent (e), with a power of 2 (`1.m * 2^e`). Is there a similar function that returns the value in a power of 10? Something like `m * 10^e` would be perfect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685181/how-to-get-the-sign-mantissa-and-exponent-of-a-floating-point-number

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thing about `frexp` is that if you are using IEEE 754 binary floating-point (or [PDP-11 floating-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928833/why-does-frexp-not-yield-scientific-notation#comment38768339_24929364)), it simply reveals the representation of the floating-point value. As such, the decomposition is exact, and it is bijective: you can reconstitute the argument from the significand and exponent you have obtained.

No equivalent reason exists for highlighting a power-of-ten decomposition function. Actually, defining such a function would pose a number of technical hurdles: Not all powers of ten are representable exactly as `double`: 0.1 and 10<sup>23</sup> [aren't](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-powers-of-ten-up-to-10-to-the-22-are-exact-as-doubles/). For the base-ten-significand part, do you want a value that arrives close to the argument when multiplied by 10<sup>e</sup>, or by the double-precision approximation of 10<sup>e</sup>? Some floating-point values may have several equally valid decompositions. Some floating-point values may have no decomposition.

If these accuracy and canonicity aspects do not matter to you, use `e = floor(log10(abs(x)))` for the base-10-exponent (or `ceil` for a convention more like the PDP-11-style `frexp`), and `x / pow(10, e)` for the base-10-significand. If it matters to you that the significand is between 1 and 10, you had better force this property by clamping.

---

**NOTE:** If what you want is convert `x` to decimal, the problem has been [studied in depth](http://www.exploringbinary.com/tag/convert-to-decimal/). The first step of a correctly rounded conversion to decimal is **not** to compute a base-ten significand as a floating-point number (not in all cases anyway; for some inputs this can be an acceptable shortcut) because in the general case, this step would introduce approximations that are not admissible for a correctly rounded conversion function. For a quick-and-dirty conversion to decimal routine (in the case you have access to `log10` but not to `sprintf`), it may be sufficient.