# Is this valid memory alignment? If not, how should this be fixed?

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault, alignment

decNumber.h:

```
typedef struct {
int32_t digits;      /* Count of digits in the coefficient; >0    */
int32_t exponent;    /* Unadjusted exponent, unbiased, in         */
                     /* range: -1999999997 through 999999999      */
uint8_t bits;        /* Indicator bits (see above)                */
                     /* Coefficient, from least significant unit  */
decNumberUnit lsu[DECNUMUNITS]; // decNumberUnit is int16_t and DECNUMUNITS is 1
} decNumber;
```

Test.cpp:

```
decNumber a,b,c;
```

When I print the addresses of a,b and c, this is what I get:

a:0x7fff0d7a9858 to 0x7fff0d7a9864

b:0x7fff0d7a9864 to 0x7fff0d7a9870

c:0x7fff0d7a987c to 0x7fff0d7a9888

Is the byte overlap of 0x7fff0d7a9864 between a and b valid? This program eventually runs into a segmentation fault. Why?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you "print the addresses"? ([Maybe related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9963401/596781))

Comment: Is there really a byte overlap? Or are you printing something like `&a + 1` or `(char*)&a + sizeof(a)`, which will give the address past the end of `a`, which can be used by another object?

Comment: Thanks for your comments Mike. I eventually figured out there was something similar being done in the decnumber library where the struct pointers were being incremented in a for loop. The reason we were running into a  seg fault was because we did not allocate enough space (specific values need to be set to have the right DECNUMUNITS) in our code for the decNumber struct.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the byte overlap of 0x7fff0d7a9864 between a and b valid?

There is no byte overlap. For example, 0 to 5 means [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] and 5 to 10 means [5, 6, 7, 8, 9].

> This program eventually runs into a segmentation fault. Why?

Impossible. The program in the question is incomplete and does not compile. It can not cause a segmentation fault, because there is no program that can run.