# Possible work-arounds over a comparison warning

Tags: c++, vector

I have written some code for detecting the Strongly Connected Components.  It runs fine, but for one warning:

> warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]

I understand it is for the following notorious code snippet (as pointed out in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30395364/6490375)):

```
int i;                              //instead of size_t i;
vector< int > sorted;
...

for(i=sorted.size()-1; i>=0; --i) {
    ...
}
```

But how do I get rid of this warning?  If I write `size_t i;`, then I get a segmentation fault (and a Time Limit Exceeded on online judges, for which the code is written).  If I use `int i;` then I get the above warning (with which I am uncomfortable, and so is my professor).

So, any work around?

**Edit**:  The code works fine on declaring `i` as an `int`.  There is no vector over (or under) flow.  Also, I do understand why there is a segmentation fault.  My question precisely is, how do I circumvent it (without any warning)?

Comment: Use unsigned int instead of int.

Comment: Tried it.  But I get the same warning.

Comment: Segfault is caused by  i>=0. It never ends loop.

Comment: You are underflowing your size_t / unsigned int

Comment: > Segfault is caused by i>=0. It never ends loop.
Unsigned values are _always_ `>= 0`.

Comment: @KIIV, correct; but that is because `i` is unsigned.  The code works like a charm on changing it to `signed`.

Comment: You have two options: count from size to 1 (zero stops the loop) and index by i-1, or reverse iterator

Comment: In case if you used `size_t i;` then in the for loop when `i == 0` then the body of loop will be executed and after that `--i` will get executed. Now since `size_t` is `unsigned int` on most platform then this `--i` will result in assigning the max value [4294967295] to `i` and this will cause segfault.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, yeah but my vector contains element at position `0`; so how do I access it without the warning?

Comment: I fully concur with Trevor's answer using reverse iteration. But if you *really* wanted to use indexes to iterate backward, `for (auto i=sorted.size(); i-- > 0;) { ...}`

Comment: Cast the size to int: `for(int i= (int)sorted.size()-1; i>=0; --i)`. It should be safe unless sorted.size() > MAX_INT, which is very unlikely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using std::vector, you may want to switch your raw indexing with iterators.

```
for (auto it = sorted.rbegin(); it != sorted.rend(); ++it) {
  // ...
}
```

This would:

- iterate over your container backwards
- remove the "sign-compare" 
  warning
- make the code objectively more readable and safer

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Vector is one of the things that I am using - I use arrays as well.  So something generic would be more helpful.

Comment: you can use global funcs `std::begin()` and `std::end()` on arrays.  Also look into range based for loops.

Comment: @user6490375, you can iterate arrays with pointers. Those serves as iterators.

Answer (score 1):

You might control the value of `i` one more than the index in the for loop, to avoid trying to make `i` less than `0`, which will cause overflow when `i` is unsigned.

```
for (i = sorted.size(); i > 0; ) {
    --i;
    ...
}
```