# Why is std::ssize being forced to a minimum size for its signed size type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

In C++20, [std::ssize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) is being introduced to obtain the signed size of a container for generic code.  (And the reason for its addition is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56217283/43534).)

Somewhat peculiarly, the definition given there (combining with `common_type` and `ptrdiff_t`) has the effect of forcing the return value to be "either `ptrdiff_t` or the signed form of the container's `size()` return value, whichever is larger".

[P1227R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1227r1.html) indirectly offers a justification for this ("*it would be a disaster for std::ssize() to turn a size of 60,000 into a size of -5,536*").

This seems to me like an odd way to try to "fix" that, however.

- Containers which intentionally define a `uint16_t` size and are known to never exceed 32,767 elements will still be forced to use a larger type than required.

  - The same thing would occur for containers using a `uint8_t` size and 127 elements, respectively.
  - In desktop environments, you probably don't care; but this might be important for embedded or otherwise resource-constrained environments, especially if the resulting type is used for something more persistent than a stack variable.
- Containers which use the default `size_t` size on 32-bit platforms but which nevertheless do contain between 2B and 4B items will hit exactly the same problem as above.
- If there still exist platforms for which `ptrdiff_t` is smaller than 32 bits, they will hit the same problem as well.

Wouldn't it be better to just use the signed type as-is (without extending its size) and to `assert` that a conversion error has not occurred (eg. that the result is not negative)?

Am I missing something?

---

To expand on that last suggestion a bit (inspired by [Nicol Bolas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56258548/43534)): if it were implemented the way that I suggested, then this code would Just Work™:

```
void DoSomething(int16_t i, T const& item);

for (int16_t i = 0, len = std::ssize(rng); i < len; ++i)
{
    DoSomething(i, rng[i]);
}
```

With the current implementation, however, this produces warnings and/or errors unless `static_cast`s are explicitly added to narrow the result of `ssize`, or to use `int i` instead and then narrow it in the function call (and the range indexing), neither of which seem like an improvement.

Comment: What about those containers which have up to 255 or 65535 elements?

Comment: A 32 bits MCU today is cheaper than an 8 bit one for most of the cases. In many of them is cheaper to use 32 bits (register size) than 8 bits, and most of the memory access is still 32 bit aligned, so I don't *think* that there's much to gain using int16_t instead of a int32_t in those cases.

Comment: For stack variables, no.  If it ends up being saved in a data structure of some kind (which is not impossible once enough templated code gets layered over it), then it might.

Comment: It is a library function, every implementation can do what they deem appropriate.  In practice it almost never matters but anybody that supports a wonky memory model ought to seriously consider throwing an exception.

Comment: I'm more surprised about the converse, that containers are still allowed to have `size()` return anything other than (any alias of) `std::size_t`

Answer (score 3):

> Containers which intentionally define a `uint16_t` size and are known to never exceed 32,767 elements will still be forced to use a larger type than required.

It's not like the container is storing the size as this type. The conversion happens via accessing the value.

As for embedded systems, embedded systems programmers already know about C++'s propensity to increase the size of small types. So if they expect a type to be an `int16_t`, they're going to spell that out in the code, because otherwise C++ might just promote it to an `int`.

Furthermore, there is no standard way to ask about what size a range is "known to never exceed". `decltype(size(range))` is something you can ask for; sized ranges are not required to provide a `max_size` function. Without such an ability, the *safest* assumption is that a range whose size type is `uint16_t` can assume any size within that range. So the signed size should be big enough to store that entire range as a signed value.

Your suggestion is basically that any `ssize` call is potentially unsafe, since half of any `size` range cannot be validly stored in the return type of `ssize`.

> Containers which use the default `size_t` size on 32-bit platforms but which nevertheless do contain between 2B and 4B items will hit exactly the same problem as above.

Assuming that it is valid for `ptrdiff_t` to not be a signed 64-bit integer on such platforms, there isn't really a valid solution to that problem. So yes, there will be cases where `ssize` is potentially unsafe.

`ssize` currently is potentially unsafe in cases where it is not possible to be safe.  Your proposal would make `ssize` potentially unsafe in *all cases*.

That's not an improvement.

And no, merely asserting/contract checking is not a viable solution. The point of `ssize` is to make `for(int i = 0; i < std::ssize(rng); ++i)` work without the compiler complaining about signed/unsigned mismatch. To get an assert because of a conversion failure that didn't need to happen (and BTW, cannot be corrected without using `std::size`, which we are *trying to avoid*), one which is ultimately irrelevant to your algorithm? That's a terrible idea.

---

> if it were implemented the way that I suggested, then this code would Just Work™:

Let us ignore the question of how often it is that a user would write this code.

The reason your compiler will expect/require you to use a cast there is because you are asking for an *inherently dangerous operation*: you are potentially losing data. Your code only "Just Works™" if the current size fits into an `int16_t`; that makes the conversion statically dangerous. This is not something that should implicitly take place, so the compiler suggests/requires you to explicitly ask for it. And users looking at that code get a big, fat eyesore reminding them that a dangerous thing is being done.

That is all to the good.

See, if your suggested implementation were how `ssize` behaved, then that means we must treat every use of `ssize` as *just as inherently dangerous* as the compiler treats your attempted implicit conversion. But unlike `static_cast`, `ssize` is small and easily missed.

Dangerous operations should be called out as such. Since `ssize` is small and difficult to notice *by design*, it therefore should be as safe as possible. Ideally, it should be as safe as `size`, but failing that, it should be unsafe only to the extend that it is impossible to make it safe.

Users should not look on `ssize` usage as something dubious or disconcerting; they should not fear to use it.

Comment: Regarding the first point, I'm thinking of tuples and variants (constructed automatically as part of generic code that is becoming more commonplace) storing the value.  In which case the developer may not have a chance to specify the type explicitly.  And yes, I was indeed trying to say that half of any size range is unsafe if it can be treated as signed.  Why are smaller-than-ptrdiff_t ranges getting special treatment here and anything equal or larger is not?

Comment: Regarding the second point, the idea was that if an algorithm uses `ssize` it should probably be treated as a logic error to use that algorithm with an inappropriately large data structure.  If the developer is allowing data to get large enough to wrap a signed size, then they should be using a data structure with a larger `size()` return type (and hence also a larger `ssize()` return type).  Again, I don't see why this is being special-cased for only a subset of sizes.

Comment: Finally, what if the developer wants to write `for (int16_t i = 0, len = std::ssize(rng); i < len; ++i)`, so that they can pass `i` to something explicitly 16-bit within the loop body without a narrowing `static_cast`?  With the current implementation, this will either raise a warning or not compile.  With my suggestion, it just works.

Comment: @Miral: "*Why are smaller-than-ptrdiff_t ranges getting special treatment here and anything equal or larger is not?*" Because making code broken is wrong. "*I don't see why this is being special-cased for only a subset of sizes.*" It's special-cased because those "special cases" can't be supported. We support the things we can support, and the cases we can't, we don't.

Comment: @Miral: "*so that they can pass i to something explicitly 16-bit within the loop body without a narrowing static_cast?*" The narrowing cast is very good, so that everyone looking at the code can say "hey, what happens if that overflows?". The mere fact that `ssize` is being used should not provoke that question. Also, what makes you think that people will more commonly write the `int16_t` version rather than the `int` version?

Comment: Promoting unsigned 32-bit to signed 64-bit is entirely possible, so *could* be supported.  But it is **not** supported, because that might be larger than `int` and so might be inconvenient.  The fundamental assumption of `make_signed` is that you're only using values in the common range of both types.  Pretending otherwise is silly.  Regardless of size, overflow should not occur unless the developer is using an inappropriate data structure for their data, if we are now wanting to declare that it's "safe" for generic algorithms to use `ssize` on most data structures.

Comment: @Miral: Your problem is that you want `ssize` to be a `make_signed` version of `size`. That's not what it is, and that's not what it is for. And yes, the idea is that it should be safe to use `ssize`, except where it is legitimately not possible to make that operation safe. That is, `ssize` is as safe as possible.

Comment: If that's not what it's for, then it seems poorly named.

Comment: @Miral: Why? Most users legitimately *do not care* about the size of the type. They care about shutting up the compiler warning about signed/unsigned comparisons. They shouldn't be punished for wanting that removed by having their generic code potentially be broken, just because some user decided to use a smaller `size_type` for their `size` function.