# Should std::ssize() still needed in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, unsigned, size-t, std-span

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56217283/why-is-stdssize-introduced-in-c20) answer that why C++20 introduced the `std::ssize()`, but according to latest [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)'s specification, the `size_type` of `std::span` is now **unsigned** `std::size_t`, so is there other use case for `std::ssize()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56217283/why-is-stdssize-introduced-in-c20

Comment: isnt this the same question as the one you link?

Comment: You didn't read the answer right. Contrary to the original form of the proposal, the Standardised `span.size()` ended up being unsigned, as in other containers. However, `ssize()` was **added** to avoid the various pitfalls already well known with unsigned sizes.

Comment: `ssisze` was not introduced even though `size_type` is `unsigned`, but because `size_type` is `unsigned`