# What does the "!= data + arraySize" mean in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, iterator, pointer-arithmetic

I was looking for a way to find a given int in my array and i found this solution

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int data[] = {23, 45, 56, 12, 34, 56};
  int target = 56;

  int arraySize = sizeof(data) / sizeof(*data);

  bool isPresent = std::find(data, data + arraySize, target) != data + arraySize;

  if (isPresent) {
    cout << "The element is present";
  } else {
    cout << "The element is not present";
  }
  return 0;
```

now i tested and it works but im wondering why there is this != data + arraySize after the find()?
Would appreciate an explanation

Comment: do you know what `std::find` returns?

Comment: you already use it here `std::find(data, data + arraySize, target)`. Do you know what it means here?

Comment: You need to read up on C++ iterators, especially this bit around how the end is represented.

Comment: `int arraySize = sizeof(data) / sizeof(*data);` would be better as `auto arraySize = std::size(data);` - `auto` would then become `std::size_t` which is the proper type

Comment: @TedLyngmo If you're going to use `std::size`, you might as well go the full route, use `std::begin` and `std::end`, and get rid of `arraySize` altogether.

Comment: There are many cases where classic arrays decay to pointers to their first element implicitly  – including adding offsets to them! `array + arraySize` thus is equivalent to `&array[0] + arraySize` (ignoring the fact that we get cyclic definition dependency as `array[0]` actually is only syntactic sugar for `*(array + 0)`…). Another case where this occurs is e.g. passing arrays as function arguments. Adding the size of an array to it (i.e. to the pointer of its first element) produces the one-past-the end pointer; always a valid address, but cannot be dereferenced.

Comment: @JamesKanze I agree and upvoted Vlad's answer for that reason. The `std::size` comment was to inspire good practice when it comes to taking the size of an array.

Comment: @TedLyngmo : unsigned is considered harmful :D see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56217283/why-is-stdssize-introduced-in-c20

Comment: @sp2danny In some situations they may be, but `sizeof(anything)` will never be negative so there's no reason to convert the `std::size_t` (whatever underlying unsigned type it has) to `int`. That may _actually_ be harmful.

Comment: @sp2danny • unsigned index is to ensure that, in theory, a container could span all of memory.  Otherwise we'd be arbitrarily constraining containers to half of memory.  So best to optimize the interface for the 0.000000000001% use case, and make the 99.999999999999% use case awkward.  Because supplying a special container for the infrequent use case would be just code bloat.  *Remember the Vasa!*

Comment: @TedLyngmo It's a question of least bad. There are very strong reasons in favor of a signed type (`std::ptrdiff_t`, for example); using an unsigned type for mathematical integers (where `-` might be used, for example) should very definitely be avoided. On the other hand, mixed signed and unsigned in expressions also creates all sorts of problems, and for historical reasons, `sizeof` is unsigned. The  most robust solution is to use a signed type, and `checked_cast` (which isn't standard) anytime you get a `size_t`. But that's overkill for a lot of code.

Comment: I'll often just assign the `size_t` to an `int`, if the context more or less guarantees that it will fit. (In a lot of cases, the semantics of the array contents ensure that it will be fairly small < 1000000000.) On the other hand, if the context is very local, I might just leave it as a `size_t`, to avoid compiler warnings. Note that because of this, and the problems involved with arithmetic values on unsigned types, I'll **never** use `auto` for an integral type. It must be immediately obvious to the reader whether he's dealing with a signed or an unsigned type.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm not that convinced, but that's on the verge of being opinionated. There are voices raised to "no-unsignedes" for sure, but personally, I have always felt them exaugurated. If doing the right thing it rarely gets wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `data` is an array (not a pointer) `arraySize = sizeof(data) / sizeof(*data)` calculates the number of elements in that array.

`data + arraySize` converts `data` to a pointer before adding `arraySize`, so the result is equal to `&data[arraySize]` which is a pointer to a (non-existent) `int` that is one-past-the-end of the array `data`.

That is a valid pointer in C++.  It is special in that it cannot be dereferenced (dereferencing causes undefined behaviour) but can (among some other things) be tested for equality to other pointers (of the same type) in C++.

`std::find()`, like a lot of other standard algorithms in the C++ standard, accepts a pair of iterators representing a range, the first identifying the beginning of the range and the second iterator representing one-past-the-end of that range.   An iterator in the standard library is (more or less) a generalised pointer.

So, in the call `std::find(data, data + arraySize, target)`, `data` is converted to a pointer (equal to `&array[0]`) and `data + arraySize` (as I described above) is equal to `&data[arraySize]` (a pointer past the end).   To `std::find()`, the pair of arguments `&data[0]` and `&data[arraySize]` means it examines all elements of the array `data` searching for `target`.

If `target` is found, `std::find()` returns an iterator that refers to the corresponding element of `array`.   Otherwise it returns the end iterator (i.e. `&data[arraySize]` in your code).

The overall expression  `std::find(data, data + arraySize, target) != data + arraySize` is then `true` if `data` contains `target`, and `false` otherwise.

In modern C++ (since C++11) the same expression may be rewritten as `std::find(std::begin(data), std::end(data), target) != std::end(data)`.    Bear in mind that `end` iterators in the C++ standard library are references to one-past-the-end of the range.

Answer (score 5):

The range of pointers to accessible elements of the array `data` declared like

```
int data[] = {23, 45, 56, 12, 34, 56};
```

is `[data, data + arraySize)`.

If the target value is not found in the array then the algorithm returns a pointer to the memory after the last element of the array that is `data + arraySize`. Otherwise the algorithm returns a pointer to the found element of the array.

Pay attention to that expression `data` or `data + 0` points to the first element of the array data. Expression `data + 1` points to the second element of the array. That is an expression like that `data + i` points to the `i-th` element of the array.

This line will be more readable

```
bool isPresent = std::find(data, data + arraySize, target) != data + arraySize;
```

if to rewrite it like

```
#include <iterator>

//...
bool isPresent = std::find( std::begin( data ), std::end( data ), target ) != std::end( data );
```

Comment: +1 for the alternative rewrite. Some of the older C++ programmers like myself might find the original quite readable, but long before there even was an `std::begin` and `std::end`, I (and a lot of others) had our own versions of these functions, to make things clearer.

Comment: I somehow feel a lack of explanation what `array + number` actually does – which might be what the question author actually hasn't understood (apart from still a good answer -> +1).