# In an std::list, is the std::distance(it.begin(), std::prev(it.end())) equal to list.size()?

Tags: c++

I am finding a behavior that I would like to understand better.

I have an `std::list<int> l;` with *N* elements, where *N>0* (non-empty).

I then compared the `std::distance` between the `l.begin()` and `std::prev(l.end())`. I was expecting this to be equal to `l.size()` because `l.end()` is an iterator that does not exist, and thus should not be accounted for in the distance.

In code form, why:

```
l.size() != std::distance(l.begin(), std::prev(l.end())
```

*Edit on why this is not a duplicate*

This question is not related to [this question on intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963401/why-are-standard-iterator-ranges-begin-end-instead-of-begin-end) because my question is about the nature of `distance` of iterators not on the nature of `l.begin()` and `l.end()` intervals, although useful and related concepts. I clearly stated that I used `prev(l.begin())` and stated why.

Given the comments in the question, I understood my conceptual error and I was going to post and answer saying that there is no guarantee that `distance()` will give you `size()`, because `distance` count **The number of increments needed to go from first to last** passed iterator, not the number of elements in a given interval. Given that the question was blocked by the deduplicator I could not answer what I think is the proper answer and add an example.

Comment: Remove `std::prev`

Comment: Could you elaborate on why my reasoning of using the std::prev is wrong?

Comment: Ranges in C++ are usually of half-open (i.e., `[begin, end)`).

Comment: Per [this example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance), `std::distance(v.begin(), v.end()) == v.size())`.

Comment: @PauloNeves work through the example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance

Comment: Oh I think i figured it out. It has to do that the distance of iterators is not what I expected. @RichardCritten: They are number of increments. I think i can answer my question then.

Comment: The distance between a and b is the number of "unit steps" you need to take to get from a to b. This is the way measuring distance usually works. Same principle: if you put ten poles in the ground, one metre apart, the distance between the first pole and the last is nine metres, not ten. If you want to "measure" how many the poles are, you need to measure the distance from a to a (possibly imaginary) eleventh pole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a list of size 1. Then `l.end()` is the [non-existent] 2nd element (index 1) and `prev(l.end())` is the 1st element (index 0). Then `std::distance(l.begin(), std::prev(l.end()))` is 0, when it should be 1.